# Activity restarts when detecting new SIM card

Tags: java, android, android-broadcastreceiver

I have been developing an application that receives the broadcast for `SIM_STATUS_CHANGED`. I have been noticing whenever i remove and reinsert the SIM in device while application is running, On detecting the SIM again after toggling `Airplane Mode`, activity recreates.

Any reason !!! Is this is default behaviour.. I have been searching on google but don't find any article about issue ...

**Manifest.xml**

```
     <receiver android:name="com.yego.util.SimChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**SimChangedReceiver class**

```
public class SimChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements WaitUtil.WaitListner {
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
SharedPrefUtil objSharedPref;
DBHelper dbHelper;
static Integer waitCount;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();
    switch (simState) {
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
            Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State absent");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
            Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State network locked");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
            Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State pin required");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
            Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State puk required");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State unknown");
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
            try {
                Log.e("MyApp", "Sim State Ready");
                objSharedPref = new SharedPrefUtil(context);
                if (objSharedPref.GetAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.device_sim_id_key).equals("")) { // No SIM Id is stored in preference
                    objSharedPref.SetAppPrefsByKey(R.string.device_sim_id_key, telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
                } else {
                    if (!objSharedPref.GetAppStringPrefByKey(R.string.device_sim_id_key).equals(telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber())) { // saved sim id does not match curent sim id
                        objSharedPref.SetAppPrefsByKey(R.string.device_sim_id_key, telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
                        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
                        Log.e("MyApp", "Executing Wait Task First Time");
                        WaitUtil waitUtil = new WaitUtil(this);
                        waitUtil.execute(1000);
                        waitCount = 1;
                    }
                }
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e);
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void onWaitaskCompleted(boolean status) {
    try {
        if ((telephonyManager.getSubscriberId() != null && !telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso().equals("") &&
                !telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().equals("")) || waitCount >= 20) {
            GetSimInfo(telephonyManager);
        } else {
            Log.e("MyApp", "Executing Wait Task"  + String.valueOf(waitCount));
            WaitUtil waitUtil = new WaitUtil(this);
            waitUtil.execute(3000);
            waitCount++;
        }
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
```

Comment: *`Activity restarts when detecting new SIM card`* That means your app getting crashed you need to share that crash log with question

Comment: Please also show us your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: No it is not crashing.. It just recreates

Comment: How is the activity defined in the manifest?
Do you see the Log.e `Executing Wait Task First Time`? What does WaitUntil actually do? Could it hang your main thread?

Comment: @peshkira `WaitUtil` is a `AsyncTask` which actually run for specified time.

Comment: @peshkira Updated my question. Added `OnWaitTaskCompleted` event

Comment: @peshkira `Log.e()` give me desired output